# jQuery.Deferred().then, how to resolve with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, deferred

So my API expects that when a particular deferred is resolved it gets 2 params.

```
fn().done(function(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(arg1, arg2);
}).fail(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Now relating to the `fn` function above, it needs to first wait for some other deferred to return before resolve.

```
function other() {
  // stubbed out to always resolve
  return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
}

function fn() {
  return other().then(function() {
    return [1, 2];
  });
}
```

But this is not working, because `arg1` will come as `[1, 2]` and `arg2` will be `undefined`. I cannot figure out how to return something from `Deferred.then()` first success filter function argument so that the resulting piped deferred resolves with multiple arguments.

Of course I can do this:

```
function fn() {
  var done = $.Deferred();
  other().done(function(){
    done.resolve(1, 2);
  }).fail(function(){
    done.reject.apply(done, arguments);
  });
  return done.promise();
}
```

But that is not nearly as elegant as using `.then()` and I now need to worry about the negative failure case API each time even though I know that I'm merely piping the rejected state through.

And yes, I could also change `fn()` api to resolve with an array, but I am really hoping there is an elegant solution to this.

Comment: The second way is not as short, but calling `resolve` *with the 2 parameters* is the correct method of passing them on.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie So I am guessing that you're saying that the answer is there is no way to do what I want to do using the `then()` function?

Comment: You could return a single anonymous object with multiple properties, which is slightly better than an array? e.g. `return {one: 1, two: 2};`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for the suggestion, I think I will just change my API to expect an object like that, because I hate having to handle the done/reject states, I'd much prefer using the `then()` pattern

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will have to invoke `resolve()` or `reject()` in order to pass multiple arguments.

`.then()` doesn't include any mechanisms for "*spreading*" a returned collection. It'll just keep the collection intact as the 1st argument.

But, it will interact with a `Deferred` or promise that's returned. From the [paragraph starting with "**As of jQuery 1.8**"](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

> These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the promise's .done() or .fail() callbacks, or **they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks**.

So, you could use your example of `other()` as the basis for `fn()` to keep it fairly succinct with another `Deferred()`:

```
function fn() {
    return other().then(function () {
        return $.Deferred().resolve(1, 2).promise();
    });
}

fn().then(function (a, b) {
    console.log(arguments.length, a, b); // 2 1 2
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cqac2/

Comment: That seems weird, `fn().done(function(a){console.log(a)})` would then log `a` as a promise object.

Comment: @codefactor A `Deferred()` or promise is the one exception with `.then()` that it won't just pass along. It will bind the promise it creates to the promise being provided to it. Example from the docs: [chaining Ajax requests](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/#example-3).

Comment: really?? awesome this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm still fairly new to this (and may be misunderstanding), but isn't the call to `promise()` in your code sample redundant, since the promise is only seen by the `then()` method, which (I imagine) isn't going to try to resolve or reject it?

Comment: @Mac Yeah, it's probably redundant. Even if `.then()` were to attempt to resolve or reject the deferred, both methods become a no-op after the state has been set (no longer [pending](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.state/)).

Answer (score 0):

The callback passed to then can return a new $.Deferred with 2 arguments like this:

```
function other() {
  // stubbed out to always resolve
  return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
}

function fn() {
  return other().then(function() {
    return $.Deferred().resolve(1, 2).promise();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can pass a variable number of arguments with the spread operator in the `$.when()` and the success function chained with `.done(//syntax)`

```
$.when(...deferreds).done(
    function (...deferreds) {
        deferreds.forEach(el => {
            console.log("resolved result", el[0].result);
        })
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("do something else");
    });
```