# JavaScript native Promise execute callback on both results

Tags: javascript, promise

Is there any way to execute callback on both results of Promise object?

For example I want to make some cleanup logic after execution of xhr request. So I need to do something like this:

```
var cleanUp = function() { something.here(); }
myLib.makeXhr().then(cleanUp,cleanUp);
```

In jquery Defered for example i can use method always():

```
myLib.makeXhr().always(function() { something.here(); });
```

Does Promise support something like this?

Comment: I see for now there is only 
then and catch methods
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
So probably no way (or extend prototype to make this)

Comment: jQuery.Deferred().then, how to resolve with multiple parameters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703887/jquery-deferred-then-how-to-resolve-with-multiple-parameters1

Comment: As Benjamin answered - no. Thats why i usually go with https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird in browser and it's join, all, and all other methods. Of course it's not native, but it's solution to lot of promise problems plus promisification.

Comment: @Jarema plus, in addition to the richer API and better stack traces it's actually considerably faster than native promises at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, there is none.** It was [discussed](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/issues/18)  but the spec is minimal. It doesn't include a bunch of other functionality. It's designed to interoperate well with library promises and to provide simple functionality.

[Here is a correct polyfill of that proposal originally made by StefPanner](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/Promise.prototype.finally).

Moreover, I disagree with the <strike>current</strike> now deleted answers adding it themselves because they're all doing it wrong (as an enumerable property - no fun). Even if we ignore what it does to the return values and error state of the returned promise. The intended way to extend native promises is by *subclassing them*, sadly, no browsers support this yet so we'll have to wait.

Instead of messing with native prototypes, we should use a different pattern:

```
openDb().then(foo).then(bar).finally(close).then(more);
```

Is susceptible to us forgetting to call close, even if we open it 100 times in our app, forgetting to close it even once can still be devastating. On the other hand - we can use the disposer pattern which some promise libraries provide built in ourselves:

```
openDb(function(db){
    return foo(db).then(bar);// chain here
}).then(more);
```

Basically - this pattern means instead of having `openDB` return a promise - we have it take a function *and* return a promise, when the function is run, if it returns a promise we wait for that promise to resolve. It looks something like:

```
function openDb(withDb){
    return justOpenWithoutCleanUp().
           then(withDb).
           then(clean, function(e){ clean(); throw e; }); // note the rethrow
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Promise object supports 'always'.

For eg:

var oPromise= jQuery.ajax({
                    url:YOUR_URL
              }).always(function(){
                  YOUR_CLEAN_UP_METHOD();
              })

Comment: @SanketPipariya It is not question, but answer

Comment: The downvoters are not telling you - but they're downvoting you for using jQuery here - it's unrelated to the question which discusses native promises.