# Catch all unhandled javascript promise rejections

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I would like to catch all unhandled exceptions/rejections that take place within a javascript Promise. Is there a good method for catching them without adding a `.catch(..)` on each end of the Promise chain? (in case of forgetting to add this, the error silently disappears).

The developer console in Google Chrome can log them, I like to log them as well in a production environment.

For normal javascript exceptions I use the `window.onerror` function, but the errors from a Promise call this function.

Example:

```
window.onerror = function (e) {
    alert("unhandled error: " + e);
};

var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var nullObject = null;
    // Raise a TypeError: Cannot read property 'forceNullError' of null
    var x = nullObject.forceNullError(); 
    resolve();
});

p.then(function () { alert('success'); });
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7zwej6L/

*) I noticed that WinJS has a `.done(..)` method for what I want, but Native Promises don't.

Comment: `.done` is equivalent to `.then(done, done);` where `done` is some function - so no great loss there

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for your response. I found this on MSDN "Unhandled exceptions in a then function are silently captured as part of the state of the promise, but unhandled exceptions in a done function are thrown." [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700337.aspx).

Comment: No, `.done` is **not** equivalent to `.then(done, done)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667598/will-javascript-es6-promise-support-done-api/26667655#26667655.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The whole world is waiting for the `unhandledrejection` and `rejectionhandled` events. As of March 2016, Chrome is now the first to support it.

Example:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
    console.error('Unhandled rejection (promise: ', event.promise, ', reason: ', event.reason, ').');
});
```

Specification: [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#unhandled-promise-rejections)

Mozilla Developer: 
[onrejectionhandled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onrejectionhandled), [onunhandledrejection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onunhandledrejection)

Chromium Issues: [495801](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=495801), [393913](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=393913)

Comment: Seems that it is already in Chromium's trunk and that Firefox really wants implement it too. I think it will be available very soon.

Comment: Edited it to correct the name of the event to "unhandledrejection", and mention that Chrome now supports it (woot!). "window.onunhandledrejection" is the property version.

Comment: FYI for anyone using Bluebird, the `unhandledrejection` event is triggered, _but_ the promise and reason are nested underneath the `detail` key of the event (e.g. `event.detail.promise` instead of `event.promise`). See http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error-management-configuration.html#global-rejection-events

Comment: Odd. For me, it only calls these functions when "Pause on caught exceptions" is enabled.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=unhandledrejection says supported in Chrome 49+, Chrome for Android 70+, iOS Safari 11.3+, UC Browser for Android 11.8+, Safari 11+, Opera 36+, Samsung Internet 5+, Android Browser 67+.

Answer (score 27):

Note that in Node the event is called `unhandledRejection`:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(err, promise) {
    console.error('Unhandled rejection (promise: ', promise, ', reason: ', err, ').');
});
```

<strike>On version 12+, node will terminate on these rejections.</strike>

Comment: notice for Node, it's `unhandledRejection` not `unhandledrejection`

Comment: @Freewind I'm sorry you found this confusing - we kept to dom event naming vs. node event naming (uncaughtException vs. onerror).

Answer (score 3):

Some libraries have their own APIs for doing this. Some browsers will report unhandled rejections (sooner or later).

Actually, `done` probably does *not* do what you want. This is why it is not part of the spec. In any case, you still have to remember to call it.

There is no reliable, cross-platform, cross-library way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

[uncaught library](https://github.com/aleksandr-oleynikov/uncaught) can help you to catch unhandled promise rejections.

And it handles uncaught errors as well.

**EDIT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../uncaught/lib/index.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    uncaught.start();
    uncaught.addListener(function (error) {
        console.log('Uncaught error or rejection: ', error.message);
    });
</script>
```

Benefit of this approach is the only one interface, which allows you to handle both uncaught errors and unhandled promise rejections.

Comment: But it based on the same `unhandledrejection ` event, so supported browsers are: Google Chrome 49+, Opera 41+, Yandex.Browser 16+.

Comment: Yes, you're right.
There isn't something special in base of this approach.
It only simplifies `unhandledrejection` and `error` events using.