# How to implement global error handling in Vue

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, vuejs2

I want to have global error handling in Vue.JS, like the error handling system in Angular 2+. I have tried so much but I could not find a good approach to implement this handling.

Imagine you have many service methods and that these methods should run one after the other (I mean inside each other) so writing then and catch method inside the prevoius service is so ugly and unclean and now I'm looking for clean way to implement such way. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 49):

As @Badgy mentioned you can install a Vue error handler to catch errors Vue encounters.  This can be done as follows:

```
 Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
   // handle error
   // `info` is a Vue-specific error info, e.g. which lifecycle hook
   // the error was found in. Only available in 2.2.0+
 }
```

The above code can be located anywhere you like in your javascript.  I locate the code just before I create my vue instance.  i.e before my  `var app = new Vue({...});` code. Because it's a global vue error handler it will handle errors from all instances of vue as well as vue components.  I find that in practice it mostly catches errors that occur in the vue render methods.

You can read more about it in the official docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler

For more general (non vue related) javascript errors you still need a global error handler like so:

```
 window.onerror = function (msg, url, line, col, error) {
     //code to handle or report error goes here
 }
```

Again, this code can be placed anywhere javascript is allowed but typically you will want to place it to run early in your javascript stack.  You can read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

And finally, to catch a "Promise rejection" (i.e. an exception throw from a Promise function) we need to listen for [`unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) events since a Promise rejection is not caught by the `window.onerror` mechanism (thanks to @Blauhirn for the tip).  In some browsers (Chrome and Edge currently) Promise rejections can be caught with the following approach:

```
 window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
     //handle error here
     //event.promise contains the promise object
     //event.reason contains the reason for the rejection
 });
```

For more info see this StackOverflow question: [Catch all unhandled javascript promise rejections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472439/catch-all-unhandled-javascript-promise-rejections)

And finally, as @jdnz points out in a comment, if you are using Vue Router, you probably want to setup [`router.onError()`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/Router.html#Methods-onError)

Comment: this is good, but doesnt catch a thrown error in production. there, you will need also `window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', () => {...})`. however, this is supported pretty much only in chrome+edge.

Comment: Setting up window.onerror will definitely catch a throw error in production.

Comment: @Blauhirn after looking into this more it looks like the event listener you mentioned is an emerging approach to catch promise rejections (exceptions thrown in a promise function.  Apparently window.error won't catch those.  Thanks for the heads up, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: One tip,  `Vue.config.errorHandler` default value is `undefined` which would be logged by `console.error`. But if the developers remove the `console` during the building with plugins like `UglifyJs`, the error log would be missing.

Comment: @xianshenglu  Thanks, that's an interesting insight! I'm unclear what, if anything, you are suggesting needs added to improve the VueJs error handling code.  Is there a way to improve the code in my answer?

Comment: Vue Router also has an error handler `router.onError()` (https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/Router.html#onerror) that picks up some errors that the Vue error handler does not.

Answer (score 2):

I hope i understood your Question Right, but this could be what you are Looking for.

> ### errorCaptured
>
> Type: (err: Error, vm: Component, info: string) => ?boolean
>
> Details: Called when an error from any descendent component is
> captured. The hook receives three arguments: the error, the component
> instance that triggered the error, and a string containing information
> on where the error was captured. The hook can return false to stop the
> error from propagating further.

[Here is more in-Depth Info About it.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorCaptured)
Be careful its Vue 2.5.0+

Comment: thanks for your participate @Badgy. can you tell me how should i implement this function ?

Comment: @hamidhasani That is a bit too in Depth for myself to explain here Right now i dont have the time. Here i suggest you this Article `https://catchjs.com/Docs/Vue`, i think it will help you perfectly. Good luck mate