# How can calling a catch() method "try catch" the exception of a promise?

Tags: javascript, exception, es6-promise

In other words, we usually cannot "try catch" an exception simply by calling another method.

But we can handle the exception of a promise by

```
promise
  .then()
  .catch();
```

or

```
promise
  .then(fulfillmentHandler, rejectionHandler);
```

If the `promise.then()` in the first case threw an exception, how can invoking `catch()`, which is a method, on that promise handle the exception that happened previously?

We usually have to handle an exception by wrapping it using

```
try {
  // doSomething
} catch (err) {
  // handle the error
}
```

so if the exception happened for the promise that the `then()` returned, doesn't the code have to handle the exception when `promise.then()` has run? Simply invoking a method on an object usually would not be able to handle its exception (in this case invoking `catch()` on the promise that `then()` returned), because there is no such wrapping?

Comment: What do you mean *"why"*? Because that's what it's *for*?

Comment: The internal code that implements `.then()` catches the exception.

Comment: *"we usually cannot "try catch" an exception simply by calling another method"* - the `then` method doesn't throw an exception, it returns a rejected promise.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is look up some promise polyfill.

Any function passed to promise, in the constructor or in `.then` a callback is internally wrapped in try-catch, and if this function throws, it will trigger next `.catch` (or throw unhandled promise rejection error).

Wrapping promise in try-catch won't, however, catch unhandled rejections as they are somewhat special. To catch them you have to use this: ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472439/catch-all-unhandled-javascript-promise-rejections))

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
    console.error(`Unhandled rejection (promise: ${event.promise}, reason: ${event.reason}).`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> if the exception happened for the promise that the `then()` returned, doesn't the code have to handle the exception when `promise.then()` has run?

The exception that would happen in the Promise returned by `then` would not have happened yet, it will only happen in the micro-task of that Promise, after the main task is done.

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then( callback )
  // still synchronously in the main task, no error yet
  .catch( console.error );
console.log( "done with main task" );

// this will only get executed in a micro-task, when the main task is done
function callback() {
  console.log( "will now throw" );
  throw new Error( "not good" );
}
```

So the Promise objects returned by these `.then()` and `.catch()` will be able to append the callbacks just fine, and nothing in the main task will throw.

---

---

The only thing that might be confusing is the Promise constructor, which will wrap exceptions synchronously:

```js
const promise = new Promise( () => {
 console.log( "will now throw" );
 throw new Error( "not good" );
} );
console.log( "yet here we are fine" );
```

But that's not really different than with Events:

```js
addEventListener( 'test', e => {
  console.log( "will now throw" );
  throw new Error( "not good" );
} );

dispatchEvent( new Event( "test" ) );
console.log( "Yet we are fine" );
```