# Promise do not bubble outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, mocha.js

I need to test function testMe using Mocha. But there is trouble when my unit test throw an error. Here is simpified example

```
function testMe(callback) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve([1,2,3]), 1000);
    }).then((result) => {
        callback(null, result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        callback(error, null)
    });
}

testMe((err, result) => {
   if(err) throw new Error();
   if(result.length < 5) throw new Error();
});
```

In this example after throw runs catch block. But I need to run catch block only after reject.

EDIT:

In this case the script never stop. I don't understand why.

```
function testMe(callback) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve([1,2,3]), 1000);
    }).then((result) => {
        callback(null, result);
    }, (error) => {
        callback(error, null)
    }).catch(() => {
        console.log('Do not throw an error but still running');
    });
}

testMe((err, result) => {
   if(err) throw new Error();
   if(result.length < 5) throw new Error();
});
```

Comment: Don't use callback parameters when working with promises!

Comment: But I need to use it. Because inside testMe I'm using horseman API.

Comment: [Use `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) to avoid calling the `callback` twice, though that still won't get you an exception; only an unhandled rejection.

Comment: No, you don't need to pass a callback to `testMe` - you should have `testMe` *return* a promise, and then check that with mocha.

Comment: If I use .then(..., ...) instead of .then().catch() I receive UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error

Comment: There is a lot of functions that receive callbacks with common interface. But one of them need to use promise inside.

Comment: The proper course of action would be to promisify all those functions of course :-) But still, you should not (cannot) `throw` in asynchronous test cases, you need to call Mocha's `done` callback with the error. (Or maybe Mocha supports promise return values, I don't know)

Comment: Bergi, I don't throw myself. Mocha throws inside expect statement.

Comment: Then `catch` that and call mocha's asynchronous callback, or make mocha aware that you are using promises.

Comment: Yes, I am using first option you promote. And there is problem.

Comment: Where is the [asynchronous `done` callback](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) in your code? Or why don't you [`return` the promise](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises)?

Comment: Done callback should be at the end of testMe callback handler.

Comment: I cannot change unit tests in this case.

Comment: The unit test you currently have will simply not work properly with asynchronous code. You *should* change it, promises or not.

Comment: Current generic unit tests works with callbacks correctly, but the problem is using a promise inside one of functions.

Comment: Well, the proper fix is to make the tests use promises. But if you absolutely want to go back from your promise function to callbacks, you can [use `.done`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667598/will-javascript-es6-promise-support-done-api). Are you using a particular promise library?

Comment: I'm using native ES6 promises

Comment: Then you can only use that `setTimeout` hack I linked.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! It's interesting and I will try tomorrow.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, it seems like correct solution. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with promises then return the promises from functions instead of taking callbacks.

For example, instead of:

```
function testMe(callback) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // ...
    });
}
```

use:

```
function testMe(callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // ...
    });
}
```

that way you will have the promise available to the caller of the function.

If you need to mix both styles, i.e. returning promises and taking callbacks, consider using a reliable library to handle that for you especially if you have trouble coding the translation between those style yourself:

- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html

Comment: But I have common mocha test that don't wait a promise.

Comment: How to use these libraries in my case?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [`return` the promise from the test](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises):

```
function testMe() {
//             ^^ drop the callback
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//  ^^^^^^ return the promise
        setTimeout(() => resolve([1,2,3]), 1000);
    });
}

var p = testMe().then(result) => {
//              ^^^^^ use the promise
   if(result.length < 5) throw new Error();
});
return p; // to mocha
```